# Get the name of all keys in a Firestore collection

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

My Firebase data structure looks like this:

[image: Firebase Data]

How can i get the name of all the keys in the first document (0) within the collection (People). The values are assigned dynamically so i can't query directly to the documents, i can only query to the Collection People.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to simply read the document.  See the documentation for [reading a document from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

```
firestore
    .collection("People")
    .document("0")
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        if (document != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
        }
    }
```

Inside the success listener, the DocumentSnapshot will contain a Map of fields to values that you can get with [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()):

```
    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        if (document != null) {
            val map = document.getData()
            // map has keys with values and values with data
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
        }
    }
```

If you don't know the ID of the document, then you can't effectively query it.  Firestore doesn't impose an ordering on the documents.  What you see in the console is simply an alphabetical list of document IDs, which has no relation to the order in which they were added.

If you need to order the documents, then you should use some field value, such as a timestamp value, and use that to query the collection to find the newest one.